# Ignore all unregistered routes in Angular 8 app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, single-page-application

We are looking into upgrading a large .Net Core / AngularJS application to the latest version of Angular. The application currently uses Razor views for each page but the goal is to move to a SPA. Since this is going  to be a very long process the only option is for us to rebuild one page or component at a time.

What I am trying to achieve is to register the SPA but have Angular kick in only for the routes I have configured in the RouterModule. If a specific route is not configured it should simply ignore it and let the request continue to .Net. I am calling app.UseSpa() before app.UseMvc() in the Startup logic.

I am not finding a way to add this ignore to the RouterModule. Is this possible, and if not then is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I guess that you could use https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions #errorHandler and replace current URL with the requested one

Comment: What is the URLs for them? Where is the difference in them? Different domains or sub-domain?

Comment: I stated that I wanted to rebuild one page at a time so it needs to be on the same domain. It is also not preferable that either the old or new pages have to be in a subfolder of the url.